# Cómo convertir base64 a varbinary

Tags: php, mssql

Busco la manera de convertir una imagen en `base64` a `varbinary` a través de `PHP`.

Estoy tratando de convertirlo de la siguiente manera haciendo una inserción exitosa en `MSSQL`:

```
CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX),$_POST(['imgBase64']) //Un trazo cualquiera
```

Pero al tratar de codificarla para mostrarla nuevamente como imagen, aparece como si no existiese y el resultado del `base64_encode($imagen)` es totalmente diferente al original...

```
Entrada: iVBORw0K...kJggg==
varbinary almacenado: 0x6956424F52773...545726B4A6767673D3D
Salida: aVZCT1J3MEtHZ2...JrSmdnZz09
```

Otras imágenes ya almacenadas en la base de datos se muestran de manera correcta, pero no funciona con las nuevas que estoy tratando de insertar.

Cuál es la manera correcta de hacer la conversión de `base64` a `varbinary`?

Comment: Creo que te falta decodificar la imagen al convertir: `CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), base64_decode($_POST(['imgBase64']))`

Comment: Gracias @Triby seguí tu sugerencia y logré el objetivo. Solo que hice el `base64_decode` fuera de la función `CONVERT` ya que me saltaba un error de `SQL`. Dejaré una respuesta para futuros visitantes ya que veo muy poca documentación al respecto en la web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias a la orientación de @Triby logré resolverlo...

Recibo la imagen en `base64` desde un formulario `HTML` y le aplico la función `base64_decode()` de `PHP`, luego paso la variable como parámetro en la función `CONVERT` de `MSSQL`... Algo similar a esto:

```
$imagen = base64_decode($_POST['imgBase64']);
$sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE(IMAGEN) 
VALUES(CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX),?))";
$params = array($imagen);
```

De esta manera, se inserta correctamente el registro en la base de datos y cuando aplico la función `base64_encode($respuesta['IMAGEN'])` de `PHP`, se muestra correctamente en el browser, la imagen obtenida del campo de tipo `VARBINARY` de la base de datos.